# Cannot change Ajax timeout in ext-js app

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm trying to override ajax timeout in a `Documentum xCP` application.

`Ext.Ajax.setTimeout(120000)` and `Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Ajax, { timeout:120000 })` didn't help. Every time an instance of Ext.data.proxy.Ajax is created, it has `timeout: 30000`. Maybe it's reverted after my call, but I don't know how to check this.

With `Ext.override` I can create new properties in `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` prototype, but existing properties don't change.

I debugging my app in `Chrome` and using the special parameter in app url to load the debug version of ext-all script.

**upd:**
If I call

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Ajax, { timeout:120004 })`
```

just once, then

```
Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.prototype.getConfigurator().values["timeout"]==120004
Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.prototype.timeout==30000
```

The value `30000` is used in `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.doRequest()`.

If I call it again:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Ajax, { timeout:120005 })`
```

then

```
Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.prototype.getConfigurator().values["timeout"]==120004
Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.prototype.timeout==120005
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `Documentum xCP` but on my web application using Ext.js (v.4.1), I used the following snippet to change general timeout:

```
    Ext.onReady(function(){
        Ext.Ajax.timeout = 150000;
    });
```

Maybe the onReady event is the key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the proxy defaults, use:

```
Ext.define(null, {
    override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Server',
    config: {
        timeout: 120000
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the proxy defaults. Put this class under **app/overrides** folder.

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.data.proxy.Proxy', {
    override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Proxy',
    timeout: 10000,

    completeOperation: function(operation) {
        try {
            this.callParent(operation);
        } catch (e) {

        }
    }
});
```

Or add your view model as give below
    Ext.define('Model', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
        alias: ..

```
    stores: {
        xstore: {
            model: 'type'

            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                timeout: 90000, // increasing time.
                url: url
            }
        }
    }
});
```